# spring boot + hibernate search + elastic search embedded fails to start

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-boot, hibernate-search

I'm struggeling to setup hibernate seach using the elastic search backend in a spring boot setup.

What I have is spring boot and the following dependencies.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0.M3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-search-backend-elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.0.Alpha3</version>
</dependency>
```

What happens is, that hibernate search initializes before elastic search has finished starting.

Using the following property exposes the rest interface as well

```
spring:
   data:
      elasticsearch:
         properties:
            http:
               enabled: true
```

Causing an exception

> Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:9200 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused: connect

Now, how do I define a dependency here?

I tried using a custom BeanFactoryPostProcessor to inject a dependency on elastic search, but that seems to be ignored in the auto configuration scenario.

Is there any way to introduce a wait until elastic search is up?

The setup works, when I set the hibernate `index_management_strategy`to `NONE`, but then the index is not configured and all custom analyzer annotations are ignored, defaulting to the default mappings in elastic search, which can not be configured in the auto configuration scenario.

Ideally elastic search should be hosted external to the jvm, but it's convenient in testing scenarios.

Comment: it tries to connect ES server on localhost, you're not running it obviously, so it's not about hibernate

Comment: Not quite, through the magic of spring boot auto configuration a single node instance is started, but in the background

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to some help from the spring boot team, I was able to solve the issue - solution [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6333).

> The problem is that there's no dependency between the EntityManagerFactory bean and the Elasticsearch Client bean so there's no guarantee that Elasticsearch will start before Hibernate. As it happens, Hibernate starts first and then fails to connect to Elasticsearch.

This can be fixed by setting up a dependency between the two beans. An easy way to do that is with a subclass of `EntityManagerFactoryDependsOnPostProcessor`:

```java
@Configuration
static class ElasticsearchJpaDependencyConfiguration extends EntityManagerFactoryDependsOnPostProcessor {

    public ElasticsearchJpaDependencyConfiguration() {
        super("elasticsearchClient");
    }

}
```

Now all that is needed is to set the number of replicas to `0` to fix the health status of the cluster in the single node deployment. This can be done by specifying an additional property in the `application.properties` file

```
spring.data.elasticsearch.properties.index.number_of_replicas= 0
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm understanding this is an issue you're hitting during integration tests.

You could have a look at how we start ES during the integration tests within Hibernate Search itself, using a Maven plugin which makes sure the server is started before the tests:
- https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-search/blob/5.6.0.Beta1/elasticsearch/pom.xml#L341-L368

N.B. this uses a custom ES configuration, tuned to start quickly even though it's only a single node cluster:
 - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hibernate/hibernate-search/5.6.0.Beta1/elasticsearch/elasticsearchconfiguration/elasticsearch.yml

Hibernate Search uses the Jest client to connect to ES, so it will require you to enable the HTTP connector of ES: let's not confuse this with a NodeClient, which is a different operating mode.

If your question isn't related to automated testing but rather production clusters, then I'd suggest using a Service Orchestrator like Kubernetes.

Comment: The maven plugin is a nice option, thanks. But probably all I need is a retry logic for the JestHttpClient, during initlal index creation say 3 times with 10s wait - it just fails immediatly, that would work.

Comment: I'd rather make sure ES is started first, but if that's what you are after then all you need to do is do send an HTTP GET on localhost/127.0.0.1 with any custom code (and wait/retry). No need to patch Jest.

Comment: Sure fixed timings are probaly not a good idea, the busy wait is exactly what I'm after .. only problem currently is that this is all auto managed by spring boot - don't want to manage hibernate myself .. so I need to introduce this wait before hibernate starts to initialize itself, but currently I'm missing the right injection point

Answer (score 1):

I checked sprint-data docs and looks like you misunderstood this piece (and actually it's confusing, guys don't understand the tech underneath?)

> By default the instance will attempt to connect to a local in-memory server (a NodeClient in Elasticsearch terms), but you can switch to a remote server (i.e. a TransportClient) by setting spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-nodes to a comma-separated ‘host:port’ list.

NodeClient is not "local server", it's special type of **ES client**. This local client can connect to ES cluster nodes containing data, and as I said in the comment, you don't have any ES data nodes running.
Read this for better understanding https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_transport_client_versus_node_client.html

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. But, it works as expected when I give the embeded NodeClient in local mode a bit more time to startup. Basically the `ElasticsearchIndexManager` tries to create the index on startup using http. If I set the index creation to NONE, this is skipped. So later when elements need to be indexed the NodeClient is up and everything works (exposes localhost:9200) - except the index mapping was not created.

Comment: Since NodeClient is "kinda" a cluster node, you indeed can connect to localhost:9200, but if you don't have data nodes it does not make any sense, it cannot be used even as a mock server. And of course you can't create any indexes or mappings with NodeClient alone

Comment: Actually you can bootstrap ES data node in the same JVM with NodeBuilder API

Comment: Well that is exactly what the Spring Boot Autoconfiguration gives me, http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-nosql.html#boot-features-connecting-to-elasticsearch

Comment: N.B. Hibernate Search doesn't use the "local server" approach but rather connects over the REST protocol using the Jest client.